# How to implement Singleton when there is an object dependency when instantiating?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I have a singleton class which requires an object to be instantiated.

I'm using this method to do so:

```
  public static AppConfig Instance(IConfigManager configManager)
    {
        if (_instanceHolder == null)
        {
            lock (LockObject)
            {
                if (_instanceHolder == null)
                {
                    _instanceHolder = new AppConfig(configManager);
                }
            }
        }

        return _instanceHolder;
    }
```

Is it the best way to implement singleton in such scenario?

Thanks

Comment: cant you encapsulate the IConfigManager  creation inside the Instance method? what is preventing you?

Comment: you could remove the second `if(_instanceHolder==null)`

Comment: @SS 'Kain': No, the point of that check is for the double-checked locking pattern. It's a bad idea, IMO, but that check is required if you're going to implement the DCL.

Comment: why is it a bad idea? that's one way to make sure thread-safety.

Comment: @user133212: It's a complex way which is easy to get wrong for minimal performance benefits. See my article for simpler options.

Comment: @Jon; your article doesn't cover any scenario where the singleton class has any dependencies on initialization.

Comment: @user133212: If you mean dependencies on user-provided values, no - because I think that's a bad idea to start with, as per my answer. But it *does* show alternatives to the DCL.

Comment: I don't see anything really wrong with DCL (I don't agree with your 4 disadvantages of the DCL that you've written) and your article is indeed irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 6):

Using a singleton in this situation seems like a very bad idea, in my view. The second call will *completely ignore* the `configManager` parameter, because it'll find there's already an instance. That violates the principle of least surprise, IMO.

The singleton pattern is *generally* nasty for various reasons, not least of which is testability. This example is even worse - definitely move away from it.

Additionally, I wouldn't use double-checked locking when implementing the singleton pattern anyway. See [my article on the singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) for my preferred choices.

Comment: There should only be one instance of ConfigurationManager in my application, that's why singleton makes sense. So what do you think should be used instead?

Comment: @user133212: I would use normal dependency injection... but if you *really* want it to be a singleton, then put an `Initialize(IConfigManager)` method which can only be called once (or it throws an exception) and a separate `Instance` property which will throw an exception if `Initialize` *hasn't* been called.

Comment: it's an asp.net application; the problem with the normal dependency injection is that it creates instances with each request which is not necessary. Why a new AppConfig instance should be created where only one instance is required in the whole application life cycle. About the singleton usage of Initialize(...) method, I don't see what advantage this has on my approach?

Comment: @user133212: It makes it clearer that you will initialize it *once* and then reuse the same instance, and that the caller doesn't get any say in which configuration is being used. Currently the caller is under the illusion that the IConfigManager they pass in will be used, when it may not be. As for the dependency injection problem - that sounds like a matter of configuring the dependency injection system properly.

Comment: I see what you mean and that makes sense. This method is only created to be used by the tests. I have another method called Instance() with no parameter which passes a ConfigManagerWrapper to the AppConfig constructor and that's used for production. So basically the production instantiation is done by the production code itself and an overloaded method is added for enabling unit testing. I haven't used any IoC for this; perhaps I should start using it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems an IoC container would be very well suited for this scenario, e.g. (using [Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject)).

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
// register implementor of IConfiguration
kernel.Bind<IConfiguration>().To<Config>();
// register AppConfig as a singleton
kernel.Bind<AppConfig>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

...

// get the AppConfig singleton
var appConfig = kernel.Get<AppConfig>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is double checking Singletone pattern. No problems here.

Comment: You don't think it's a problem that a second call to `Instance` with a different `IConfigManager` will silently give you an instance referring to the first one? Even ignoring that, I *think* you need `_instanceHolder` to be declared `volatile` for this to be correct code, and we can't see that declaration.

Comment: @Jon Skeet; I'm using volatile. Volatile makes sure the assignment is completed before the instanceHolder becomes accessible/readable.

Comment: @user133212: Sure, but my point was that without having seen that in the question code, alexanderb can't possibly say that there are no problems. As I've said, I'd avoid DCL anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I use a singleton it is only to refactor away from a greater evil, namely a class full of static methods. One trick I have used when I need to pass in a dependency for construction is to have two "instance" methods (or a "construct" and an "instance" method): one that takes an argument and one that doesn't. The one that takes an argument must be called first, and will throw an Error if called again. The no-parameter version will throw an error if it is called before the other one.

This means you have to be careful when using the singleton, but at least you should find out quickly at run time if you are doing it wrong. I'm hoping (in my case as well as yours) that this is just a step on the way to something better.

I'm using Java but I presume things work pretty much the same in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Following Jon's recommendation:

```
 public static void Initialize(IConfigManager configManager)
    {
        if (_instanceHolder == null)
        {
            lock (LockObject)
            {
                if (_instanceHolder == null)
                {
                    _instanceHolder = new AppConfig(configManager);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new ApplicationException("Initalize() method should be called only once.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instances the specified config manager.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static AppConfig Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instanceHolder == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Singleton instance hasn't been initialized.");
            }

            return _instanceHolder;
        }
    }
```

and I call this on:

```
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppConfig.Initialize(new ConfigManagerWrapper());
    }
```

I should ideally be using an IoC container for this.
But I liked to enable the AppConfig class to have a default implementation as well as enabling it to be used for dependency injection. In which case, i didn't have to call the Initialize() method on production.